# If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $X$ is a totally bounded metric space, is $f(X)$ also bounded?

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, alternative-proof

If $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces and $X$ is totally bounded and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous (not necessarily uniform), is it true that $f(X)$ is also bounded? How can we prove it or is there any counter example?

I tried:

$f(x)=\tan x$ for $\pi/2<x<\pi/2$, then $X$ is bounded but $f(X)$ is unbounded.

Is my counterexample correct? If not, is there any better counterexample? Or maybe is $f(X)$ bounded and how can we prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: No correct because f(x) is not continuous on $x = \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct.  $1/x$ on $(0,1)$ is easier.